# For a sequence $a_1\geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq c$ which is bounded from below by $c$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> For a sequence $a_1\geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq c$ which is bounded from below by $c$. Define the order of net $\{a_{{\beta}}\}$ is $a_{\alpha}\leq a_{\beta}$ iff $a_{\alpha}\subset a_{\beta}$. My question:
>
> Is the $\inf a_n=\lim a_n$?
>
> Is the same for the net $\{a_{{\beta}}\}$? How to describe a similar theorem in the net? That is, if net $\{a_{{\beta}}\}$ is bounded below from $c$. Do we have
> $$\lim_{\beta}a_{\beta}=\inf_{\beta}a_{\beta}=I$$
> for some constant $I$.

My idea: Suppose $a_{\beta}\to a$. I feel like, for the net, the definition of convergence is for a neighborhood U of $a$, there exists $\beta_0$, such that $\beta \geq \beta_0$, $a_{\beta}\in U$. So how to describe the net bounded by constant?

Comment: The definition you gave for a convergence of a net is unacceptably sloopy for lack of proper quantification.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I do not give any new definition...

Comment: How do you translate $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a$ into nets?

Comment: @DavidKraemer That is $a_1\leq a_2$ iff $a_1 \subset a_2$.

Comment: For you first question about sequences, it is true by the monotone convergence theorem for sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(a_\beta)_{\beta \in I}$ be a net of real numbers such that $a_{\beta} \leq a_{\beta'}$ if and only if $\beta \leq \beta'$ in the sense of the directed set. Let $a = \inf \{ a_{\beta} : \beta \in I\}$, and suppose $a > -\infty$. We claim that $a_\beta \to a$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. It suffices to show that $|a - a_\beta| < \varepsilon$ eventually. Indeed, by definition of the infimum there exists $\beta \in I$ such that $a_{\beta} < a + \varepsilon$. Then for all $\beta' \in I$ with $\beta' \leq \beta$ one has $a \leq a_{\beta'} < a + \varepsilon$, as needed.

Comment: Is the same in the language of topology? For example, $a_\beta$ is eventually in the neighborhood of $a$?

Comment: Without loss of generality on $\mathbb{R}$ the neighborhoods are balls. $a \leq a_\beta < a + \varepsilon$ implies that $a_\beta$ is in the $\varepsilon$ ball of $a$.

Comment: But without metric, how do you use the $\epsilon-$range? And my net is actually the partition of a finite closed interval. So the order $\leq$ is just the $\subset$. In your way, how to describe the infimum? $a_\beta < a+\epsilon$ is what?

Comment: I was assuming the Euclidean topology. You have to be careful if you are using a different topology. For example this theorem is false for the discrete topology.

Comment: Another question: for the net, how to define the net is decreasing?